# JS hiding a div while targeting anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple divs (`class="profile"`) wich are hidden by default. Each div is only shown when targeted. I want all divs with `class="employeeul"` to be hidden when one of the profile divs is targeted. I don't get this working with css, does anyone know why? A JS solution is good as well. (I think I can't use something like onclick, because the divs must hide when the anchors are accessed from other sites.)

This is my code (I removed the divs content):

```
<div class="narrow_content">
        <div class="profile" id="m_empfang0"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_empfang1"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mitarbeiter0"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mitarbeiter1"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mitarbeiter2"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mitarbeiter3"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mieter0"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mieter1"></div>
        <div class="profile" id="m_mieter2"></div>
    <div class="employeeul">
        <ul> <!-- Empfang -->
            <li class="employee"></li>
            <li class="employee"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="employeeul">
        <ul> <!-- Mitarbeiter -->
            <li class="employee"></li>
            <li class="employee"></li>
            <li class="employee"></li>
            <li class="employee"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="employeeul">
        <ul> <!-- Mieter -->
            <li class="employee"></li>
            <li class="employee"></li>
            <li class="employee"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "targeted"? Are you wanting the lists below to display when you mouse over the top div with class='profile'

Comment: You did not make any anchor!

Comment: Please Checkout [**this DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/netuvo/1/#profile).

Comment: I meant with targeting, if you have the address example.php#m_mitarbeiter0. I want all employeeul the be hidden if the user targets one of the ids.

Comment: How are you hiding your divs?  If you're using CSS and setting the display property to "none", all you have to do is change the display property to "block" for divs when you want them displayed.  If you're comfortable using jQuery, [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) will do this for you.  If you're not comfortable with jQuery and this comment targets your issue, let me know and I will write an answer with a js equivalent.

Comment: if you're using php, you should include a tag for that.

Comment: @Kathy
The `class="profile"` is hidden via `display: none;`. But that's not the problem. I can't get the `class="employeeul"` to be hidden.  I never used jQuery and this project already requires JS, so a solution with JS would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just need the syntax for displaying/hiding items dynamically when the page has a specific url.  In that case, here is a simple JS solution:

```
//get an array of elements with the class we're interested in working with
var employeeuls = document.getElementsByClassName("employeeul");

//get the current url
var url = window.location.href;

//if the current url is equal to example.php#profile, hide some elements
if(url == "example.php#profile")
{
    //iterate over the array and apply the style to hide the elements
    for(i=0; i < employeeuls.length; i++)
    {
    employeeuls[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

//otherwise, the elements should be hidden
else
{
    //iterate over the array and apply the style to hide the elements
    for(i=0; i < employeeuls.length; i++)
    {
    employeeuls[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

NOTE:  "block" is the default display property for unordered lists.

I understand you're not using jQuery, but I'm going to include the jQuery equivalent for anyone viewing this post in the future:

```
//variable assigned to all elements with class "employeeul"
var employeeuls = $(".employeeul");

//get the current url
var url = $(location).attr("href");

//apply the style change 
if(url == example.php#profile)
{
employeeuls.hide();
}

else employeeuls.show();
```

Comment: Basically this is what I'm looking for!
Right now I'm struggling with the event listener. The event should be triggered if the url is example.php#profile*

Comment: Okay, I'll update my answer to reflect that.  Hey - do me a favor and accept this as the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If by targeting, you mean the hash value in the URL, you just need to write some JS to grab that hash value and toggle the css. Then toggle show/hide (or a visibility class via jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $profiles = $('.profile'); // Store all the profiles in a query
    var hashTarget = location.hash.replace('#', ''); // Returns hash value

    function showTargetedDiv(){
        $profiles.hide(); // Hide any divs that may previously be showing
        $('#' + hashTarget).show();
    }

    showTargetedDiv();
    $(window).on('hashchange', showTargetedDiv); // Event handler

});
```